# Collections: Why are Vectors not used anymore but are still around?

Tags: java, collections

I'm writing some code to do some SSH jobs on a remote machine and one of the methods I'm (forced of) using returns a Vector type. I've learned about them several years ago but never had the chance of actually using them until now.

What I do know about them is

1. They are not thread safe
2. They are very old and are deprecated (Netbeans warns me it's an "Obsolete Collection")

Not being thread-safe seems not that of a big of a deal if you're being careful about it. but I don't think it's enough to dismiss them. Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

It seems I've touched a serious issue here with Vectors being obsolete(deprecated may not be the right word), what I want to know is why are vectors being so avoided in the first place

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep a programming language backwards compatible vs. fixing its flaws](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/191858/keep-a-programming-language-backwards-compatible-vs-fixing-its-flaws)

Comment: are vectors "flawed" ?

Comment: Your question already has answers on Stack Overflow: [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1386275/1521179)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java8 Vector's source, there is no depracated notice.

There is the following comment in the header :

> Unlike the new collection
>    implementations, {@code Vector} is synchronized.  If a thread-safe
>    implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use {@link
>    ArrayList} in place of {@code Vector}.

Fuerthermore you can use Collections.synchronisedList() with an ArrayList as parameter to replace what a vector is able to do.

But otherwise, no Vector works well.

If you really don't like it do :

```
List l = new ArrayList(myFunctionThatReturnAVector());
```